# iOS app crashes when authenticating with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

My app blows up when trying to sign in from iPhone simulator. This is a new project and I'm following the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth). When I fill in both input fields and then hit the sign in button, the simulator crashes with `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1`

**LoginVC:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var loginEmailInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginPasswordInput: UITextField!

    @IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = loginEmailInput.text, let password = loginPasswordInput.text {

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

            }

        } // breakpoint here
    }

}
```

I've added my app's identifier to the Firebase Console. Installed the correct pods. Added `FIRApp.configure()` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I'm lost now. Have I missed something?

I've `import Firebase` in `AppDelegate.swift`. Do I need to import it in other controllers?

Comment: Not clear, what is your error? This code, should work as is (just tried it). Did you connect the outlet?

Comment: Hi @Idan I'm very new to swift. I have just googled "breakpoint 1.1" and it turns out I have set a breakpoint somewhere. I think I need to delete it?

Comment: Yes. Delete the breakpoint or simply press continue if you want to keep the break point.

Comment: Found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working as expected.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var loginEmailInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginPasswordInput: UITextField!

    @IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = loginEmailInput.text, let password = loginPasswordInput.text {

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

            }

        } // breakpoint here
    }

}
```

From comments, we realized that there is an accidental breakpoint in xcode. Which might seem like the program breaks at that point. The breakpoint actually pauses the run of the program and allows to examine your code.

The little blue arrow on the line number the breakpoint:

[image]

You can:

- Disable it by clicking on it
- Delete it by right clicking on the button and selecting `Delete Breakpoint`